# How do I scroll at some div?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a long page which doesn't fit on screen and at the end of the page I have one div:

```
<div id="scrollableDiv"> some contents here..</div>
```

I want that when the page loads I directly want to come to this div and not show the top of the page i.e normally you would see the top of the page. But I need to show this div which has id of "scrollableDiv" which is present at the end of the page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
window.onload=function(){location.hash = "#scrollableDiv";}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `scrollTo` function:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('scrollableDiv');
window.scrollTo(0, elem.offsetTop);
```